# why on button click the language translation table do not appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have making my own CV using html and javascript and i want two options in my language for language-change(i choose html-Java script it would be a good sample as i am beginner).

I have two tables for english and french CV each inside div "eng-tab" and "frc-tab" respectively.

What i want is:
On running  my code must show default as english CV whereas and it will **also contain two button french and english for language translation** so that when user wish to translate it to french he will click french button and it will replace the english CV by the french version of CV (by div containing "frc-tab") on same place.

What is the problem in my code?

(1.) The problem is when i run my code it shows the default CV without any problem but when i click on any button to change the translation it shows none of the CV . I don't know why ? Any solution to this problem ?

Comment: can you create a fiddle of what you have posted here...also the code is incomplete at the bottom section of your code(tags are not closed)

Comment: @TanyaSinha thanks for the reply i have edited question and have added the full code. (I have no idea of using fiddle :'( )

Comment: you can post your code here [ http://jsfiddle.net/ ]

Comment: @TanyaSinha here it is http://jsfiddle.net/a29ypzm7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code has errors of divs..divs are not properly closed and also you have to import jquery plugin in your code http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js

Here is the updated fidle [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a29ypzm7/2/)

JS:

```
$(function () {
$(".frc-tab").hide();
$(".eng-tab").show();


 $('.eng').on('click', function (event) {
     $('.eng-tab').show();
     $('.frc-tab').hide();

 });

 $('.frc').on('click', function (event) {
     $('.eng-tab').hide();
     $('.frc-tab').show();

 });

})();
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<button class="eng">english</button>
<button class="frc">french</button>
</div>
<!-- here is english translation-->
<div class="eng-tab">
<table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center" style="margin: 0px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td valign="top">
                <!--container-->
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="11" align="center" width="621" bgcolor="#f7f3e6" background="images/bg-stamp-2.jpg" style="border-width:11px; border-color:#ccc; border-style:solid; background-color:#f7f3e6; background-image: url('http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/bg-stamp-2.jpg'); background-position: right top !important; background-repeat: repeat-x;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" border="0" style="border: none; ">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="padding-bottom: 13px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 19px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Shekhar Singh SHEKHAWAT</h1>

                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Studnet residence</h1>

                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Tel : 06.52.53.46.69</h1>

                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Email : shekhar.paris@gmail.com</h1>

                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="middle" width="88" style="
                                                    padding-right:22px; padding-top:20px;">
                                                <img width="118" height="80" src="http://perso.esiee.fr/~georgesj/esiee/pic/esiee_paris_logo.gif" alt="">
                                            </td>
                                            <tr></tr>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit">
                                                <img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">In search of job(Software development using C/ C++/ C#/ Silverlight/ Wpf/ Asp.Net/ MVC-MVVM) </h1>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit">
                                                <img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <!--Formation-->
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Formation: </h1>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <!-- BKBIET -->
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2008-2012 :</h1>

                                                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Bachelors in computer science in engineering from B.K. Birla Institute of Engineering and technology-Pilani (India).</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!---->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Professional  Experience(21 months total): </h1>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Axestrack -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2015:January-June (6 months internship) : </h1>

                                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;"> <a href="http://www.axestrack.com/">Axestrack</a> is originated by IIT-Bombay and BITS-Pilani and IIM educated good experienced engineers in reputed MNCs like Microsoft. The company developed a software which tracks the location, speed, direction, fuel management, stoppage time, route deviation, door lock, car lock etc. of vehicle and notify the Fleet Manager through Sms or email. My task is "Multiple Responsive UI Integration with Tracking Services" in this existing software. Technologies used are : C#(MVC-5),Asp.net, javascript, html5, css, SqlServer, MongoDB, Perl, SCRUM.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- MIPS Laboratory -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2011 : January-February (2 months) :</h1>

                                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">In <a href="http://www.mips.uha.fr/anglais/">MPS-Laboratory</a> was working on a AutoMotive application using Visual C++ and RTMAaps. Objective was to determine the appropriate speed of the car according to the current road context (using camera and sensors in RTMaps) under a real time software called RTMaps using Visual C++ . Necessary tools were developed for 2 level data fusion of information provided by several specialized sources using the concept of the belief theory.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Langues/Informatiques -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit">
                                <img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Language -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Language: </h1>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">French :</h1>

                                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">DELF-B2 certified in French language by ministry of education of France(<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipl%C3%B4me_d'%C3%A9tudes_en_langue_fran%C3%A7aise">DELF</a>- Diplôme d'études en langue française)</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">English :</h1>

                                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Very Good</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">Hindi :</h1>

                                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Very Good</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Informatique -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Informatique: </h1>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Centres d’intérêts -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit">
                                <img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Centres d’intérêts: </h1>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Centres d’intérêts details -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Voyages découvertes, lecture, internet, cuisine, cricket, culture, langue.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!-- here is english translation ends-->
<!---->
<div class="frc-tab">
<table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center" style="margin: 0px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td valign="top">
                <!--container-->
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="11" align="center" width="621" bgcolor="#f7f3e6" background="images/bg-stamp-2.jpg" style="border-width:11px; border-color:#ccc; border-style:solid; background-color:#f7f3e6; background-image: url('http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/bg-stamp-2.jpg'); background-position: right top !important; background-repeat: repeat-x;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" border="0" style="border: none; ">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="padding-bottom: 13px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 19px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Shekhar Singh SHEKHAWAT</h1>

                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Résidence étudiante</h1>

                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;"> 4 Allée Buissonnière, 77186 Noisiel</h1>

                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Tél : 06.52.53.46.69</h1>

                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Email : shekhar.paris@gmail.com</h1>

                                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Nationalité : Indien</h1>

                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="middle" width="88" style="
                                                    padding-right:22px; padding-top:20px;">
                                                <img width="118" height="80" src="http://perso.esiee.fr/~georgesj/esiee/pic/esiee_paris_logo.gif" alt="">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit">
                                <img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Recherche d'emploi(développement C/ C++/ C#/ Silverlight/ Wpf/ Asp.Net/ MVC-MVVM) </h1>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit">
                                <img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--Formation-->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Formation: </h1>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- BKBIET -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2008-2012 :</h1>

                                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Baccalauréat technologique en informatique à Birla Institute of Engineering and Technology en Inde.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- ESIEE-Paris -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2012-2014 :</h1>

                                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Master en Génie informatique à ESIEE Paris. (Diplôme d'ingénieur)</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!---->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Experience Professionnel (21 mois total): </h1>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Axestrack -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2015:Janvier-Juin (6 mois stage) : </h1>

                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;"> <a href="http://www.axestrack.com/">Axestrack</a> fournit la solution pour le suivi du véhicule. Nous avons développé un logiciel qui permet de suivre la Localisation du véhicule, la vitesse, la direction, la gestion du carburant, temps d'arrêt, la déviation de la route,verrouillage de porte, verrouillage de voiture, etc. de véhicule et Informer le gestionnaire de la flotte par SMS ou e-mail. Technologie utilisié sont C#(MVC-5),Asp.net, javascript, html5, css, SqlServer, MongoDB, Perl, SCRUM</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Lusis -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2014:Avril-Octobre (6 mois stage) : </h1>

                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Stage chez Lusis-Paris pour le développement d’un logiciel dans le cadre d’une croissance dans le domaine de la finance nous faisons développement sliverlight pour le développement d'une nouvelle application de pricing permettant de fournir des prix personnalisés pour nos clients. Ce système doit permettre de paramétrer les différentes composantes du flux de prix (spread, skew, band volume, bid dans toutes les dimensions du flux de prix c#-silverlight). (Équipe de 3 personnes)</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ESIEE-Paris -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2014 : Février- Avril (3 mois de stage):</h1>

                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Stage à ESIEE-Paris pour le développement de optimale Binary File Compresser utilisant c/c++/c# (console application) et c#-silverlight (web application), Utilisé advance datastructure).</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- LMS Siemens -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2013 : Mai- Août (4 mois de stage) : </h1>

                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Stage chez Siemens (LMS – Division à Roanne) pour le développement de logiciel AMESim en LMS à l’aide du c++ (Intégré AMESim avec Microsoft Windows API).</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- MIPS Laboratory -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2011 : Janvier-Février (2 mois de stage) :</h1>

                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Stage chez MIPS laboratoire à ENSISA Mulhouse pour travaille sur RTMaps en c++. Le projet était de trouver la bonne vitesse de voiture utilisant les Caméras et des Capteurs virtuelle (RTMaps) selon le contexte routier actuel.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Langues/Informatiques -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit">
                <img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Language -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Language: </h1>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">Français :</h1>

                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Intermédiaire (Presque niveau B2 de DELF- Diplôme d'études en langue française)</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">Anglais :</h1>

                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Très bonne maitrise</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">Hindi :</h1>

                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Très bonne maitrise</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Informatique -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Informatique: </h1>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- MIPS Laboratory -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2011 : Janvier-Février (2 mois de stage) :</h1>

                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">C, C++, C#, Java, Xml, Xaml, Html,css, javascript, Silverlight, .net , Asp.net, Uml, OpenGL, OpenCV, RTMAps,Visual Studio, Ubantu/Linux , Microsoft Windows.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Centres d’intérêts -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit">
                <img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                 <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Centres d’intérêts: </h1>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Centres d’intérêts details -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">Voyages découvertes, lecture, internet, cuisine, cricket, culture, langue.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: @taniya really thanks. but one question. what do this http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js do in this code ? (i hope its like including library in c++ and c). I mean it still run without any error using this library so why we included it ?